# Print all Digrams and their frequencies in a string

Tags: java, string, user-input

I'm trying to write a program that reads a string of text and prints all digrams in this text and their frequencies. A digram is a sequence of two characters. The program prints digrams sorted based on frequencies (in descending
order).

Example of input: `park car at the parking lot`

Corresponding output: `ar:3 pa:2 rk:2 at:1 ca:1 he:1 in:1 ki:1 lo:1 ng:1 ot:1 th:1`

I have this implementation but it only works for every character in the string. How would I implement this for every digram?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Digrams {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int ci, i, j, k, l=0;
    String str, str1;
    char c, ch;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a String : ");
    str=scan.nextLine();

    i=str.length();
    for(c='A'; c<='z'; c++)
    {
        k=0;
        for(j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            ch = str.charAt(j);
            if(ch == c)
            {
                k++;
            }
        }
        if(k>0)
        {
            System.out.println("" +c +": " +k);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you've already got perfect answers and much much better than this, but I was wondering if I can sort the result in descending order without the help of `Collections` Class, it may be of help, or a new idea.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Digrams{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert The Sentence");
        String []sentence =  in.nextLine().split(" "); // split the input according to the spaces and put them in array

        //get all digrams
        ArrayList<String> allDigrams = new ArrayList<String>(); // ArrayList to contain all possible digrams
        for(int i=0; i<sentence.length; i++){ // do that for every word     
            for(int j=0; j<sentence[i].length(); j++){ // cycle through each char at each index in the sentence array
                String oneDigram= "";
                if(j<sentence[i].length()-1){
                    oneDigram += sentence[i].charAt(j); // append the char and the following char
                    oneDigram += sentence[i].charAt(j+1);
                    allDigrams.add(oneDigram); // add the one diagram to the ArrayList
                }
            }
        }

        // isolate digrams and get corresponding frequencies
        ArrayList<Integer> frequency = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // for frequencies
        ArrayList<String>  digrams = new ArrayList<String>(); //for digrams
        int freqIndex=0;
        while(allDigrams.size()>0){ 
            frequency.add(freqIndex,0);
            for(int j=0; j<allDigrams.size(); j++){ // compare each UNIQUE digram with the rest of the digrams to find repetition
                if(allDigrams.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase(allDigrams.get(j))){
                    frequency.set(freqIndex, frequency.get(freqIndex)+1); // increment frequency    
                }
            }
            String dig = allDigrams.get(0); // record the digram temporarily
            while(allDigrams.contains(dig)){ // now remove all repetition from the allDigrams ArrayList
                allDigrams.remove(dig);
            }
            digrams.add(dig); // add the UNIQUE digram
            freqIndex++; // move to next index for the following digram 
        }


        // sort result in descending order
        // compare the frequency , if equal -> the first char of digram, if equal -> the second char of digram
        // and move frequencies and digrams at every index in each ArrayList accordingly
        for (int i = 0 ; i < frequency.size(); i++){
            for (int j = 0 ; j < frequency.size() - i - 1; j++){
                if (frequency.get(j) < frequency.get(j+1) || 
                      ((frequency.get(j) == frequency.get(j+1)) && (digrams.get(j).charAt(0) > digrams.get(j+1).charAt(0))) ||
                        ((digrams.get(j).charAt(0) == digrams.get(j+1).charAt(0)) && (digrams.get(j).charAt(1) > digrams.get(j+1).charAt(1)))){ 
                    int swap  = frequency.get(j);
                    String swapS = digrams.get(j);
                    frequency.set(j, frequency.get(j+1));
                    frequency.set(j+1, swap);
                    digrams.set(j, digrams.get(j+1));
                    digrams.set(j+1, swapS);
                }
            }
        }


         //final result
         String sortedResult="";
         for(int i=0; i<frequency.size(); i++){
             sortedResult+=digrams.get(i) + ":" + frequency.get(i) + " ";
         }

         System.out.println(sortedResult);

    }

}
```

**Input**

```
park car at the parking lot
```

**Output**

```
ar:3 pa:2 rk:2 at:1 ca:1 he:1 in:1 ki:1 lo:1 ng:1 ot:1 th:1
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to check for every 2 letter combination, and look for those instead. You can do this by using a double for-loop, like so:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int ci, i, j, k, l=0;
    String str, str1, result, subString;
    char c1, c2, ch;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a String : ");
    str=scan.nextLine();

    i=str.length();
    for(c1='A'; c1<='z'; c1++)
    {
        for(c2='A'; c2<='z'; c2++) {
            result = new String(new char[]{c1, c2});
            k = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
                subString = str.substring(j, j+2);
                if (result.equals(subString)) {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if (k > 0) {
                System.out.println("" + result + ": " + k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This also means you have to compare Strings, rather than comparing chars. This of course means the `.equals()` function needs to be used, rather than the `==` operator, since String is an object in Java.

Result for me was:

`ar: 3 at: 1 ca: 1 he: 1 in: 1 ki: 1 lo: 1 ng: 1 ot: 1 pa: 2 rk: 2 th: 1`

Comment: Do you know how I could print the digrams based on frequencies in descending order?

Comment: The way I would do it, is to save all found digrams in a `Map<String, Integer>`. With the key of the `Map` referring to the digram itself and the value of the digram referring to the amount of times it occurs. 
After aquiring this `Map`, can simply use `Collections.sort()` to sort this map based on the value.

Comment: How does one use `Collections.sort()` to sort a map?  This idea is new to me.

Comment: Ah, let me rephrase myself. What I would do is turn the `Map` into an entrySet by calling `Map.entrySet()`. I just realised this returns a `Set` and not `List`, since I usually just call `Map.entrySet().stream()`, but converting a `Set` to a `List` is trivial. Anyway, this resulting `List` of entries can then be sorted based on the value of each entry.

(I am starting to realise this is a lot less of a hassle when using the stream API from java 8)

Comment: So you're writing a `Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>`, then using it to sort the `List`?  I see.  I was slightly fooled by the word "simply" in your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a String : ");
        String str = scan.nextLine();

        ArrayList<String> repetition = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> digrams = new ArrayList<String>();
        String digram;

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
            digram = str.substring(i, i + 2);
            if(repetition.contains(digram) || digram.contains(" ") || digram.length() < 2)
                continue;
            int occurances = (str.length() - str.replace(digram, "").length()) / 2;
            occurances += (str.replaceFirst(".*?(" + digram.charAt(0) + "+).*", "$1").length() - 1) / 2;
            digrams.add(digram + ":" + occurances);
            repetition.add(digram);
        }

        Collections.sort(digrams, (s1, s2) -> s1.substring(3, 4).compareTo(s2.substring(3, 4)));

        System.out.println(digrams);
}
```

If you don't want to use jdk8 then let me know.

Comment: this is for an intro to java class and we haven't learned the Collections class yet. Could you show me how to do it without it?

Comment: It's really not worth it to sort list manually. If you want to I can explain to you briefly how sort method works. Otherwise you will have to implement sorting algorithm for example bubble sort etc.

Comment: I think this counts incorrectly if there are three of the same letter in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it in one line:

```
Map<String, Long> digramFrequencies = Arrays
    .stream(str
        .replaceAll("(?<!^| ).(?! |$)", "$0$0") // double letters
        .split(" |(?<=\\G..)")) // split into digrams 
    .filter(s -> s.length() > 1) // discard short terms
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/NDM11u).

This works by:

- doubling all letters not at start/end of words, eg `"abc defg"` becomes `"abbc deeffg"`
- splitting into pairs, re-starting splits at start of word
- discarding short terms (eg words like "I" and "a")
- counting frequencies